# Показать содержимое одного div в другом div без его копирования

Tags: forms, jquery, ajax, html, javascript

Суть такая, что на странице есть две одинаковые формы которые имеют ajax-валидацию. Но срабатывает она только на одной из них, так как идентификаторы формы одинаковые. Одна форма показывается при нажатии на кнопку в раздвигающемся блоке, а вторая при нажатии кнопки и во всплывающем окне.

**Вопрос:** как можно сделать так, что бы загрузить форму только один раз, а при нажатии на кнопки просто ее показывать с привязкой всех событий к ней?

Спасибо

Comment: Дать формам разные id и валидацию делать соответственно! Не сложно id'шники указать через запятую?!

Comment: id формы выводиться из бд. Если дать разные id, то и записи скорее всего полетят не туда

Comment: Если это поможет, то работает это все на CMS Joomla + RS Form Pro

Comment: В таком случае присваивать какойто префикс, Типа form23_pref

При отправке запроса отсекать этот префикс!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никаких временных атрибутов не надо, если у вас уже есть переменная указывающая на форму, то вы просто можете переместить ее используя `.append()` или `.html()`

```
$(function () {
    var $form = $('#first form');
    $form.submit(function () {
        if ($form.find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length > 0)     ('#errors').text('не все галочки поставлены').show(200).delay(2000).hide(200);
        else return true;
        return false;
    });
    $('#to_first').click(function () {
        $('#first').append($form);
    });
    $('#to_second').click(function () {
        $('#second').html($form);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/mKgs8/)

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос.

Как вам такой вариант?

```
<div id="uniqueid" type="">
<div id="anybutton">Кнопка на форме</div>
</div>
```

Обработка будет такой:

Если окно всплыло, то атрибут type делаем "window" иначе "page"

```
$('#anybutton').click(function(){

if ($('#uniqueid').attr('type')=='page') alert('Clicked from page');
else alert('Clicked from window');
});
```

Comment: Не совсем то. Или я в не понял Вас.
У меня сейчас так:
button#A
<div id="from#A"></div>
button#B
<div id="from#B"></div>
где #A это кнопка и место определенное для формы внутри страницы, а #B это кнопка и место для вызова и вывода формы в окне. По умолчанию форма выводиться в #A, а #B пустой и копирует содержимое при клике. 
Вот надо или переносить содержимое из #A или форму вообще выводить в каком-то другом месте, а потом показывать то там, то там в зависимости от условий

Answer (score 0):

«Как сделать» — много вариантов. Уточните, чего при решении вы хотите *избежать*: в какую часть кода не залезать, а в какую можно, например.

Вариант, предполагающий, что событиями нажатия кнопок вы рулить можете/готовы.

Форму плагином выводить один раз, в скрытый `div` и сразу поменять все `id` на временные, напр. дописать префикс: `elementId -> tmpl_elementId`. При "нажатии кнопки" для раздвигающегося окна, или второй, для всплывающего, `jQuery.clone()` блок формы в соотв. раздвигающееся или всплывающее окно + менять `id` на "рабочие" для `RS_Forms`. Причем, по закрытии его, или "Отмене", надо стирать содержимое соотв. окна, чтобы не было конфликта со вторым.

Comment: С временными id я уже пробовал. Не хочет работать или я не на том этапе их менял. Хотя я ставлю временные сразу после загрузки и меняю на нужные как только на кнопку нажали. 

Я уже готов на любое решение и лезть куда угодно